# Assigning a Razor var using a Javascript function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

On this page, a user fills out a web form, and it gets added to the list when created.
I want to filter the list so a logged in user will only see forms they made themselves.

I have some Razor code that runs a foreach loop through all available items, and I have Javascript that rips the currently logged in user's info.

is it possible to assign this data to a var in the razor code?

ex.

```
@{var user = getUser(); //want something like this }

@foreach (var item in Model) {


    //add check if item.name == user.name here

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
           etc etc

<script> 
    function getUser() {$.getJSON('GetLoggedUserInfo', function(data) {
         return data;
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is a good idea to have this logic in a view. View should be as 'dumb' as possible.
You could make item filtering at data storage level or at least in controller:

```
return View(items.Where(x => x.name == user.name))
```

Comment: Worked great! As a follow up question, can I pass a second parameter to the View? Because I want a user to to be able to see certain links only if they're above a certain user group, so sending a simple bool would be nice, but doesn't seem possible.

Comment: You can pass any amount of parameters. ViewData/ViewBag would be suitable for that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way. You can get current user properties using:
       `HttpContext.Current.User`